# Make javascript Animation function loop, Until page loads

Tags: javascript, animation, loading, loader

I have a piece of javascript that I have copied & edited, that is designed for an animated loading ring but the animation only runs once, I would like it to run every 4 seconds, until the page is loaded, but I can't find the right syntax/script to get it to repeat, i do not want it to reload the page only loop that specific script until i set it to stop.

".radial" is the class of the radials contained inside my css & html files.
there is twelve of them & they do-not rotate only the fluorescent .glow animation part makes it appear as they are rotating. the code is;

```
const radials = [...document.querySelectorAll('.radial')];
let degrees = 29;

for(i=0; i < radials.length; i++) {
  degrees += 13;
  radials[i].style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
  degrees += 34;
}

radials.forEach((radial, index) => {
  setTimeout(function() {                                           
    radial.classList.add('glow');                                               
  },index * 29);
});
```

**:: Update ::**

Having read the comments below and searching on Youtube. I think that wrapping the whole script in a function, would be the best option. Including a call to that function within its self & passing it an argument in the parenthesis of a timeout or delay property. But *setInterval()* & *setTimeOut()* both use the unsafe *eval()* function underneath. Which is supposed to be a security concern.

Also a youtube video I watch a while ago, said that *setInterval()* & *setTimeOut()* do not achieve 60fps. requestAnimationFrame() Would be A much better option. I'm not sure how legitamate these claims are, or where his sources were from but I will continue searching the Webs.

The glow part looks good but I just haven't been able to get it to repeat.
I am new to Js please be patient.

is there any other workarounds for the *setTimeOut()* & *setInterval()*.?

Comment: I have tried searching on youtube and have also tried set interval but doesn't seem to do much, I also tried setting a function afterwards which called the const radials part back up but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Place this code into a function that is passed to a **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** timer call.

```
function loop() { 
  const radials = [...document.querySelectorAll('.radial')];
  let degrees = 29;

  for(i=0; i < radials.length; i++) {
    degrees += 13;
    radials[i].style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
    degrees += 34;
  }

  radials.forEach((radial, index) => {
    setTimeout(function() {                                           
      radial.classList.add('glow');                                               
    },index * 29);
  });

  setTimeout(loop, 4000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your reply. The setInterval() function is only governing the time delay before the animation starts. Not looping at 4000ms intervaals

Comment: @RyanStone Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. In that case, you wouldn't actually use a loop at all, you'd have a recursive function call. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @RyanStone Which loop is supposed to have the 4 second delay, the `for i` loop or the `forEach` loop or both?

Comment: I am unsure if it is the "for i" loop or the "forEach", just trying to loop/repeat the intire command, so when it runs one full cycle and all radials are glowing then it resets and goes back to a dull grey, then the glow starts to fill them again..

Comment: @RyanStone OK, let me make another adjustment.

Comment: Still not working i'm affraid!! Doh.... Lol, its only loading one radial now instead of all of them.... Have tried something I've just seen on youtube called window.requestAnimationFrame but i still can't get the syntax or sequenceing of the code right

Answer (score 0):

Use [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). The setInterval takes two parameters, the first is the function you want to run and the second is your repeat time in miliseconds. So to run a function every 4 seconds you would do:

```
setInterval(function() { 
 // do something
}, 4000);
```

Comment: I just tried this but it is still only running once, is the a parameter where i can set the intervals inside that function you just mentioned like in css where you say 2s 3s 4s etc

Comment: Still not seem to be working, I know the }, index *29 section is what I've been changing to set the duration of the annimation but have tried both the answers above... No luck so far, thanks for your replies though..

Comment: What exactly goes wrong with Scott Marcus answer? I'll try to refine it and get to what you need.

Comment: I tried the Scott Marcus answer but it doesn't seem to replay, it only animates once and then it stays with all radials in the glow state..

Comment: with the setInterval(function() answer is there not a parameter to set repeat or is this standard with the 4000ms line

Comment: Just played around with this and the set interval function is governing the time delay before the animation starts when the page loads....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `setInterval`, as in the other answers, but I think that the logic is clearer if you have an `animate` function that keeps calling itself.

You are adding a "glow" class, but you are never removing it. The `animate` function should toggle it on and off. To make it crystal clear, let's make that a separate function, `toggleGlow`.

Next, each animation loop we kick off the individual `toggleGlow` functions with a different delay for each radial.

Finally, the animate function will re-call itself after a short, constant, delay each time, until some stop condition is met (like the page loading).

```
const radials = [...document.querySelectorAll('.radial')];

function toggleGlow(element) {
  if (element.classList.contains("glow")) {
    element.classList.remove("glow");
  } else {
    element.classList.add("glow");
  }
}

function animate() {
  radials.forEach((radial, index) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      toggleGlow(radial);
    }, index * 29);
  });

  if (!stopCondition) {
    setTimeout(animate, 200);
  }
}

// kick it off
animate();
```

JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/duxhy3Lj/

Comment: No, there is around 22 radials, in the formation of a clock but the do not animate 1 by one, (if it were a clock 2pm, 5pm, 7pm, 9pm, & 11pm all start to glow at the same time and then the other remainders fill in clockwise with the glow) the actual radial's do not rotate, although I may add this in later on its just the glow aspect that appears asif it is rotating.... I will try your suggestion..

Comment: I mean, yes. It is the .glow class which I am trying to animate.

Comment: I think the rotate section that your refering to is the part that is drawing more than one radial at different degrees round the clock, they are static not moving at the moment

Comment: Oh, I see. So why was that part of your example code? That was confusing. So you're trying to animate the glow, but you only ever turn it on? How is that supposed to animate? Do you ever take away the glow class?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question your asking, the rotate part is just what is seperating the radials appart from each other, by a set number of degrees. the .glow function is animating the glow class in a circular motion, but they all end up glowing and I woul like it reset back to no glow at the end of each cycle

Comment: @RyanStone I updated my answer and created an example that works.